# CSS scrollbar despite div height + margin adding up to 100%

Tags: html, css, margin, positioning

- I somehow lost track of what I am doing wrong here:
- I got a simple content `<div>`.
- it has a `height` of `100% - 30px` and a `margin-top` of `30px`, ...so together they add up to `100%` of the parent elements height.
- the parent element is the body with `height` set to `100vh`. No margins, no paddings.
- However I do still get a y-scroll bar on the right. Can anyone explain to me, why that is?

I put a minimal example here to show what I mean:
https://jsfiddle.net/kemo8npa/4/

Can someone explain to me, why i get the scrollbar?

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: purple;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  content
</div>
```

edit: changed example to be more minimal.

Comment: margin of content collapse with the body margin so you end with 100vh + 30px

Answer (score 0):

The `margin-top` of `.inner` adds 30px outside of the element, so the sum is 100% height again.

You could use `padding-top` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's kind of my point: margin + height add up to 100%, so there should not be a scrollbar. The header is `position: fixed`, meaning it should be out of the layout flow and not add anything to it.

I made a more stripped down example that shows what I do not understand here: https://jsfiddle.net/kemo8npa/4/

Why do I get the scrollbar? O.o